# createDrawerNavigator | undefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, navigator, drawer

I'm trying using React Native to create a drawer navigator at an Android project, but i'm gettin a "undefined is not a function", [like in this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7zt8.png)

here is the code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import {
  NavigationContainer,
  DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme,
} from '../../../node_modules/@react-navigation/native';

import {
  Provider as PaperProvider,
  DefaultTheme as PaperDefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme as PaperDarkTheme,
} from '../../../node_modules/react-native-paper';

import { DrawerContent } from './screens/DrawerContent';

import MainTabScreen from './screens/MainTabScreen';
import SupportScreen from './screens/SupportScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import BookmarkScreen from './screens/BookmarkScreen';

import { AuthContext } from './components/context';

import RootStackScreen from './screens/RootStackScreen';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const App = () => {
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  // const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null);

  const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(false);

  const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: true,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null,
  };

  const CustomDefaultTheme = {
    ...NavigationDefaultTheme,
    ...PaperDefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...NavigationDefaultTheme.colors,
      ...PaperDefaultTheme.colors,
      background: '#ffffff',
      text: '#333333',
    },
  };

  const CustomDarkTheme = {
    ...NavigationDarkTheme,
    ...PaperDarkTheme,
    colors: {
      ...NavigationDarkTheme.colors,
      ...PaperDarkTheme.colors,
      background: '#333333',
      text: '#ffffff',
    },
  };

  const theme = isDarkTheme ? CustomDarkTheme : CustomDefaultTheme;

  const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGIN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGOUT':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
    }
  };

  const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    loginReducer,
    initialLoginState
  );

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (foundUser) => {
        // setUserToken('fgkj');
        // setIsLoading(false);
        const userToken = String(foundUser[0].userToken);
        const userName = foundUser[0].username;

        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        // console.log('user token: ', userToken);
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', id: userName, token: userToken });
      },
      signOut: async () => {
        // setUserToken(null);
        // setIsLoading(false);
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
      },
      signUp: () => {
        // setUserToken('fgkj');
        // setIsLoading(false);
      },
      toggleTheme: () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
        setIsDarkTheme((isDarkTheme) => !isDarkTheme);
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // setIsLoading(false);
      let userToken;
      userToken = null;
      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      // console.log('user token: ', userToken);
      dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if (loginState.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
        <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
          {loginState.userToken !== null ? (
            <Drawer.Navigator
              drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
            >
              <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={MainTabScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="SupportScreen" component={SupportScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="BookmarkScreen" component={BookmarkScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          ) : (
            <RootStackScreen />
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If I change the "createDrawerNavigator" to "createStackNavigator", like

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
```

TO

```
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

&&

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

TO

```
const Drawer = createStackNavigator();
```

It works perfectly, but I don't want a stack, I want a drawer.

I've installed the react-navigation like this:

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

And I had to make a few changes in MainActivity.java, that now is looking like this:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

      /**
       * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
       * rendering of the component.
       */
      @Override
      protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Tracker";
      }
    
      @Override
      protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
          @Override
          protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
           return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

Here is all the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation": "^0.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.6",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
```

Can somebody PLEASE help me??

Comment: react-navigation version?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the dependencies, but now I edited the question, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

All I had to do was install react-native-reanimated and NOT to do the manual steps that the documentation shows. (In my case, undo the manual steps)
Seems like there it shows the steps to react-native-reanimated@alpha, (version 2.x.x) that looks like it's still not working properly, specially with createDrawerNavigation.

`yarn install react-native-reanimated@alpha` NO

`yarn install react-native-reanimated` YES

Answer (score 1):

Change interpolate to interpolateNode