# createDrawerNavigator : undefined is not a function while correctly imported

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I've been struggling for hours with this. Trying to use a Drawer navigator as described here :

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

followed all the installation instructions.
My React native app was working fine, setup using expo.

[image: error in emulator]

I've re-installed dependencies several times.
checked  react-native-reanimated  and react-native-reanimated/plugin in babel.config.js.
I've installed react-native-gesture-handler and imported it, first line in App.js.
I've cleared everything ".expo", "node_modules", package-lock.js several times, launched using "npx expo start -c" to empty cache.

nothing is working. I'm out of ideas.

here are my dependncies :

```
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.1",
  "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
  "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.3",
  "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "6.2.1",
  "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "6.2.1",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.6.1",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "6.2.1",
  "expo": "^48.0.17",
  "react-native": "^0.71.8",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
  "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
  "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
  "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
  "react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.21.8"
},
```

here is the babel config:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};
```

Here is the metro.config.js :
(needed as drawerNavigator seems to load typescript files, it avoids an error on loading the drawer module)

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("ts");
defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("tsx");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

This issue here seems pretty similar but the given solution is outdated :
[createDrawerNavigator | undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510916/createdrawernavigator-undefined-is-not-a-function)
( never used "react-native-reanimated@alpha" at all )

Thanks in advance for any help!